# Why do I keep getting videos darker than the frames from which they were made regardless of the software I use?

Tags: software, lighting, export

I have tried using both VSDC and VideoPad for editing videos, and both of them randomly darken the videos I put into them. Is this a common issue? If not, what information do you need me to give to solve this problem?

This is a problem I have had on multiple computers now.

Here are some side-by-side comparisons, with each pair being first the input video and then second the output video.

[image]

[image]

You can see that this second image is darker.

[image]

[image]

You can see that this second image is darker also.

**Edit:** I tried editing the video with FFmpeg, and it did the same thing.

**Edit 2:** Here are the outputs of `ffmpeg -i [videofile]`:

Original video:

```
Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
Duration: 00:01:32.75, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1012233 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: huffyuv (HFYU / 0x55594648), bgr0, 1920x1080, 1012406 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 60 tbn, 60 tbc
```

Edited video:

```
Duration: 00:01:36.98, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 514031 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (MJPG / 0x47504A4D), yuvj422p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1920x1080, 512695 kb/s, 59.99 fps, 59.99 tbr, 59.99 tbn, 59.99 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
```

**Edit 3:** The original video was compiled from a series of `.png` files. Here is the command I used to do so:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i %05d.png -c:v huffyuv -pix_fmt rgb24 output.avi
```

Comment: Share the console output of `ffmpeg -i videofile`

Comment: @Gyan I added part of the console outputs. Are they what you were looking for? If not, should I post the full output? All I removed was all of the `--enable` arguments and the versions of FFmpeg's various libraries.

Comment: How were the source videos generated/captured - which app and settings?

Comment: @Gyan It was a series of `.png` files compiled as frames into a video using FFmpeg. I added the command I used to my question.